# Integrating $\int \ln(x^2-2x-3)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I need to integrate this:

$$\int \ln\left(x^2-2x-3\right)\,dx$$

I'm thinking of going this direction:

$$\int \ln\left(x^2-2x-3\right)\,dx=\int \ln((x-3)(x+1))\,dx$$

Which would then equal $$\int \ln(x-3)\,dx + \int \ln(x+1)\,dx$$

What do you think? I guess I could also go this way: $$u=\ln\left(x^2-2x-3\right) \; \; \; dv=1\,dx$$ meaning I could integrate by parts. Which way is the best way? Can I only choose one?

Answer (score 4):

For $x>3$ we obtain:
$$\int\ln(x^2-2x-3)dx=\int\ln(x+1)dx+\int\ln(x-3)dx=$$
$$=(x+1)\ln(x+1)-(x+1)+(x-3)\ln(x-3)-(x-3)+C=$$
$$=(x+1)\ln(x+1)+(x-3)\ln(x-3)-2x+C.$$

Comment: Ok, how did you get the second line? That's where I'm getting confused right now.

Comment: @DevHeavy it's an integration by parts: $\int\ln{x}dx=x\ln{x}-\int x\cdot\frac{1}{x}dx=x\ln{x}-x+C$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll give it a go myself and see what happens. I've been doing integration for about 8 hours now. It's starting to make less sense every second.

Comment: Could you check the answer below this one and look in the comments to confirm that my answer is correct? If I put it through an online calculator, it seems that I'm missing a $-2x$ @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @DevHeavy I checked your solution. I think there is a mistake in your computations.

Answer (score 3):

Beside to Michael answer, you may use integration by parts, i.e., by taking

$$\ln(x^2-2x-3)=u, dx=dv$$ over a valid interval and so it leads you to do a partial fraction way for the rest.

Comment: I ended up doing it your way. It seems my and Michael's method was just making it more complicated. Could you take a quick look at this and confirm my answer is correct? $$\int ln(x^2-2x-3)dx=xln(x^2-2x-3)-3ln(x-3)-ln(x+1)+C$$ Would the interval for this be $x > 3$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts:
$$F(x)=x\ln{[(x+1)(x-3)]}-\int x \cdot \frac{2x-2}{(x+1)(x-3)}dx = x\ln{[(x+1)(x-3)]} - \int \left(2-\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{3}{x-3}\right)dx$$
Can you finish?

Comment: $$=2x-ln(x+1)+?$$That is how far I got. I'm having trouble figuring out where the 3 goes. @farruhota

Comment: Yes, it is $2x-\ln{(x+1)}+3\ln{(x-3)}+C$.

Comment: Oh, duh. I'm tired! I forgot I was doing each term as its own integral. I was just supposed to move the constant 3 outside. Thank you! Still, I can't help but think it is wrong somehow: https://www.integral-calculator.com/# doesn't get the same result. Although, it may be equivalent.

Comment: When the like terms are collected, the final answer will be the same as that of Michael Rozenberg.